# vb.net add a condition on a datacolumn

Tags: vb.net, dataset, conditional-statements

I have a project on visual studio using vb.net and a dataset using the Northwind Database.

In the DataTable Orders there are several DataColumns, I want to create a condition between 2 DataColumns. To be more specific I want the value on the DataColumn OrderDate to be less than the ShippedDate.

How can I do that?

Comment: You are conditining columns you are conditioning rows correct? and this is a filter. So to clarify you want a filter where OrderDate is less than ShippedDate, Correct?

Comment: Can you be more specific? I can't tell what you are asking for.

Comment: Yeah, something like a filter, for example i have a datagridview bound to the dataset, and I can add records, I want everytime I add a record to check if the orderdate is less than the shipped date, I mustn't use validating though. As you said I want a filter that will not let any rocrds to be saved in the dataset unless the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

I will take a guess. You can't conditioning columns but rows and this is a known as filter. So, if it is filter what you need this is way to do it:

```
Dim table1 as DataTable = //loaded from Northwind
Dim view as  DataView = Table.DefaultView

view.RowFilter= "OrderDate < ShippedDate"
DataTable FilteredTable = view.ToTable()
```

And you can find additional examples here:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/